# Missing } in less generating dynamic classes using loop

Tags: less

I would like to generate classses as such

```
.w1 { width: 1%; }
.w2 { width: 2%; }
...
.w99 { width: 99%; }
.w100 { width: 100%; }
```

I have created a LESS loop, however, it is complaining that I am missing a bracket.

```
Expected '}' but found 'i' on line 39 in file '/css/general.less':
 [38]:   (~".w@{index}") {
 [39]:      width: @{i}%;
       --^
 [40]:   }
```

I have counted the brackets. Have I positioned it wrongly? Where is my error?

```
@iterations: 100;

.width-loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {
     (~".w@{i}") {
        width: @{i}%;
     }
    .width-loop(@i - 1);
}
.width-loop(@iterations);
```

Comment: What Less compiler (and what version) do you use? That kind of `(~".w@{i}")`of syntax was removed from Less language a long ago. Normal Less syntax for the same is `.w@{i}`. Consult [the docs](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-selectors) when not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of "index" use "I".  Change`(~".w@{index}") {` to `(~".w@{i}") {`

EDIT:
remove the brackets from the line in question (i'm adding an escape to the %)

```
 width: @i ~'%';
```

EDIT: (NO SPACE BEFORE THE % SIGN)

```
@iterations: 100;

.width-loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {
     (~".w@{i}") {
        width: ~"@{i}%";
     }
    .width-loop(@i - 1);
}
.width-loop(@iterations);
```

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. However, the same error remains. I have updated the question with the correction.

Comment: I'm having trouble posting a reply so I edited my answer.

Comment: this is working now. any idea on how to remove the space between the output number and percentage sign?